# Can I authenticate rabbitmq connection using aws roles, and how?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, amazon-iam, pika

I am hosting a rabbitmq cluster on AWS EC2. Is it possible for my remote application to authenticate a connection to the rabbitmq server using AWS IAM roles or any other way using AWS services? The reason is that my IoT devices will have AWS credentials configured, but I do not want to install SSL certificates individually on each of them. I am using Python pika library and my application currently works with plain credentials (username/password) in the dev environment.

Comment: No, IAM does not directly provide any APIs so that it can be used to authenticate non-aws *managed* apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot although why not store the credentials in [secrets manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) then allow the credentials for your IoT device to read from that?

Comment: Thanks that is the kind of lead I was looking for.